# Combine two columns in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have column 1 and column 2, and want to combine them into column 3 of the same table. If the column 2 is null then display column 1 value, if column 1 is null, them display column 2 data. If both of them are null, then display null. I tried two things:

1) using CONCAT
`SELECT CONCAT(Column1, Column2) AS Column3 FROM TEST_ATTRIBUTES`.

It just merges the columns only when both of them are not null. otherwise it just prins null.

2) using (column1 + column 2).

`SELECT (Column1 + Column2) AS Column3 FROM TEST_ATTRIBUTES`.

doesn't show desired output.

I'm writing this code in java.
Thanks

Comment: are there any chances that both columns are not null?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use `COALESCE()`, this doesn't concatenate but returns the first non-null value from the list.

```
SELECT Column1, 
       Column2, 
       COALESCE(Column1, Column2) AS Column3 
FROM   TEST_ATTRIBUTES
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01885/2)

if there are chances that both of them are null,

```
SELECT Column1, 
       Column2, 
       IF(Column1 IS NULL AND Column2 IS NULL, NULL, CONCAT(COALESCE(Column1,''), COALESCE(Column2,''))) AS Column3 
FROM   TEST_ATTRIBUTES
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01885/1)

Comment: I tried in SQL editor and it works, but in my java code it is doing nothing.

Comment: `sqlMerge = "SELECT attribute1Name, attribute2Name,  IF( attribute1Name IS NULL AND attribute2Name IS NULL , NULL , CONCAT( COALESCE( attribute1Name,  '' ) , COALESCE( attribute2Name,  '' ) ) ) AS attribute7Name FROM TEST_ATTRIBUTES";`

`con.stmt.execute(sqlMerge);`

Comment: is `stmt` a wrapper class? what does `execute()` do?

Comment: stsmt is the statement, execute() method just executes the query. I have other statements and they work normally. I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: `"SELECT attribute1Name, attribute2Name, attribute3Name, attribute4Name, attribute5Name, attribute6Name IF( attribute1Name IS NULL AND attribute2Name IS NULL AND attribute3Name IS NULL AND attribute4Name IS NULL AND attribute5Name IS NULL AND attribute6Name IS NULL , NULL , CONCAT( COALESCE( attribute1Name,  '' ) , COALESCE( attribute2Name,  '' ) , COALESCE( attribute3Name,  '' ) , COALESCE( attribute4Name,  '' ) , COALESCE( attribute5Name,  '' ) , COALESCE( attribute6Name,  '' ) ) ) AS attribute7Name FROM TEST_ATTRIBUTES";`

Comment: I'm trying to use this for 6 columns and I'm getting error in syntax, what's wrong with this query?

Comment: you missed comma, before `IF` statement. `attribute6Name, 
  IF(...`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF( attribute1Name IS NULL AND attribute2Name IS NULL AND attribute3Name IS NULL'

Comment: you missed comma, before `IF` statement. `attribute6Name, 
  IF(...`