# MySQL SELECT AS combine two columns into one

Tags: mysql, sql

Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062825/combine-two-columns-in-one-column), I tried to use COALESCE as part of a MySQL query that outputs to a csv file using SELECT As to name the column names when exporting the data.

```
SELECT FirstName AS First_Name
     , LastName AS Last_Name
     , ContactPhoneAreaCode1
     , ContactPhoneNumber1
     , COALESCE(ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1) AS Contact_Phone 
  FROM TABLE1
```

I wanted 3 columns: First_Name, Last_Name and Contact_Phone

I am getting 5 columns: First_Name, Last_Name, ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1 and Contact_Phone

How do I hide the merging of ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1 into a single column for Contact_Phone from within the query?

Comment: Just leave the columns you do not want to see out of your query.

Comment: `COALESCE` returns the first non-null field. So if ContactPhoneAreaCode1 is not null then Contact_Phone will equal ContactPhoneAreaCode1.  You want to use the function `CONCAT`

Answer (score 169, accepted):

If both columns can contain `NULL`, but you still want to merge them to a single string, the easiest solution is to use [**CONCAT_WS()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws):

```
SELECT FirstName AS First_Name
     , LastName AS Last_Name
     , CONCAT_WS('', ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1) AS Contact_Phone 
  FROM TABLE1
```

This way you won't have to check for `NULL`-ness of each column separately.

Alternatively, if both columns are actually defined as `NOT NULL`, [**CONCAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) will be quite enough:

```
SELECT FirstName AS First_Name
     , LastName AS Last_Name
     , CONCAT(ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1) AS Contact_Phone 
  FROM TABLE1
```

As for `COALESCE`, it's a bit different beast: given the list of arguments, it returns the first that's not `NULL`.

Comment: How can you insert spaces inside the CONCAT_WS? By adding `' '` does not work.

Comment: Works fine in terminal, check how the query is passed to MySQL Server and how results are processed.

Comment: Ahh yes. Thanks. I was not setting the space `' '` at the beginning but in between the columns :-P

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to list ContactPhoneAreaCode1 and ContactPhoneNumber1

```
SELECT FirstName AS First_Name, 
LastName AS Last_Name, 
COALESCE(ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1) AS Contact_Phone 
FROM TABLE1
```

Answer (score 8):

You do not need to select the columns separately in order to use them in your CONCAT.  Simply remove them, and your query will become:

```
SELECT FirstName AS First_Name
     , LastName AS Last_Name
     , CONCAT(ContactPhoneAreaCode1, ContactPhoneNumber1) AS Contact_Phone 
  FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: I think you want CONCAT

Answer (score 2):

In case of `NULL` columns it is better to use `IF` clause like this which combine the two functions of : `CONCAT` and `COALESCE` and uses special chars between the columns in result like space or '_'

```
SELECT FirstName , LastName , 
IF(FirstName IS NULL AND LastName IS NULL, NULL,' _ ',CONCAT(COALESCE(FirstName ,''), COALESCE(LastName ,''))) 
AS Contact_Phone FROM   TABLE1
```