# MySQL call that combines two Tables with several identical rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-concat

My Question aims to an specific SQL call that combines two Tables.

I have two tables which I can not combine into one, because one is imported from the two every day from a file. What I need exactly, I show you here:

SQL Table 1 snippet:
[image]

SQL Table 2 snippet:
[image]

Inside the PHP source code i need this result:

```
Array(122, 146, 234, 400)  
Array(John, Dave, Sam, Jana)  
Array(SOME, SOME, Array(ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE), SOME)  
Array(Some Text…, More…, Array(More…, More…, More…, More…, More…), More…)
```

The rows of "num" must each match with Table 1, together:

```
Array(male, male, male, female)  
Array(false, true, false, true)
```

What i found is this Question:
[MySQL SELECT AS combine two columns into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860233/mysql-select-as-combine-two-columns-into-one)

So i can use `CONCAT` to combine `ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE`.
I can call each table alone and build the result in PHP or call both tables together. What is the better way?

What I don't know is a nice overall concept. Can anybody give me an example please?

**EDIT:**

I understand the syntax now. This is a nice short solution:

```
mysql > SELECT DISTINCT num, name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT prefs ORDER BY prefs SEPARATOR ', ') AS array FROM `table1` AS t1 INNER JOIN `table2` AS t2 ON t1.num = t2.num GROUP BY num ORDER BY num
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data you need, you can use a simple `SELECT...JOIN`  query:

```
select
  T1.num,
  T1,name,
  T2.prefs,
  T2.text,
  T1,gender,
  T1.opt,
from
  Table1 as T1
inner join
  Table2 as T2 on T1.num=T2.num
order by
  T1.num
```

From here, you could build the arrays by processing each row as you read it from the DB (using PDO with associative fetch)

```
while ($row=$query_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $a1[]=$row['num'];
  $a2[]=$row['name'];
  $a3[$row['num']][]=$row['prefs']; // Store values in a subarray according to num
  $a4[$row['num']][]=$row['prefs']; // Store values in a subarray according to num
  $a5[]=$row['gender'];
  $a6[]=$row['opt'];
}
```

Unfortunately, you will end up with multiple entries in arrays 1,2,5,6. To cure this, use `array_unique`:

```
$array1=array_unique($a1);
$array2=array_unique($a2);
$array5=array_unique($a5);
$array6=array_unique($a6);
```

If you don't want to use array_unique, you could use:

```
while ($row=$query_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $a1[$row['num']]=$row['num']; // Gets round the array_unique
  $a2[$row['num']]=$row['name'];// Gets round the array_unique
  $a3[$row['num']][]=$row['prefs']; // Store values in a subarray according to num
  $a4[$row['num']][]=$row['prefs']; // Store values in a subarray according to num
  $a5[$row['num']]=$row['gender']; // Gets round the array_unique
  $a6[$row['num']]=$row['opt']; // Gets round the array_unique
}
```

But then you would need to use `array_values` to extract just the values:

```
$array1=array_values($a1);
$array2=array_values($a2);
$array5=array_values($a5);
$array6=array_values($a6);
```

To get the resultant multi-dimensional arrays, you have to do a bit more processing:

```
$array4=array();
$array5=array();

//Loop through each sub array
foreach ($a4 as $subArray)
{
  //If there is only one element, store that value, otherwise store the sub-array
  $array4[]=(count($subArray)>1) ? array_values($subArray) : array_shift($subArray));
}

//Loop through each sub array
foreach ($a5 as $subArray)
{
  //If there is only one element, store that value, otherwise store the sub-array
  $array5[]=(count($subArray)>1) ? array_values($subArray) : array_shift($subArray));
}
```

(You could probably get flash by using variable variables but for clarity I went with separate loops)

Once you have the data in the arrays, you can do what you want with it. If you want to build PHP source code from it, use `var_export($arrayName,true)` and capture that into a variable

None of this code is actually tested but it will, hopefully, point you in the right direction

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed example DaveyBoy!

Comment: Works perfekt with `JOIN` statement! Please help me with CONCAT_WS to combine the other fields of the duplicate rows (comma serparated) in the result.

Comment: The `var_export` command will output valid PHP code. If you do something like `$c=var_export($array3,true)`, `$c` will contain the string `Array(SOME, SOME, Array(ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE), SOME)` (albeit with some formatting changes)

Answer (score 0):

Please use CONCAT in MYSQL as you will get the result directly from one query instead of processing it via PHP.

Comment: Ok, i prefer the direct solution too but i had never used it.

Comment: How is the use of CONCAT_WS inside @Hara Prasad's SQL call?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result= mysql_query("select * from table1 t1,table2 t2 where t1.num=t2.num order by t1.prefs asc");
```

Use the function mysql CONCAT_WS() -> Concatenate With Separator

```
CONCAT_WS(",",FIELD_NAME,FIELD_NAME)
```

Comment: Thanks Hara, i will test your code example right now!

Comment: @HaraPrasad : Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted. A number of your answers have been flagged as low quality and will be deleted if you do not edit them.

Comment: It worked well but there is no grouping. How is the use of CONCAT_WS in your SQL call?