# Select statement to display the result with combination of 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I am new for developing.Kindly bear my codings. I have created a table arlog with id(auto increment), status, ticket number and code. Ticket and code number is set as unique. That is the duplicate of this combination cannot inserted again. But individually ticket number or cpt can be inserted as many times.It works fine. Now I want to use select query with another table with respect to the arlog table ticket number and code.Here is the select statement

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ar` C WHERE    provider='".$_SESSION['PROVIDER']
."' AND C.`TicketNo`  IN ( SELECT TicketNo FROM `arlog` L where L.status NOT IN('New','Completed','Completed(Ar_aging)
','Completed(Rework)','Rework','Completed_Followup','Completed_Supervising'  ) 
    and L.assign='".$_SESSION['NAME']."' )  order by id desc") or die(mysql_error());
```

The query check the ticket number in arlog and displays correcly. But I want to combine TicketNo and Code in the arlog. I have made research but could not find solution. First of all is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Please try following sql:

```
 SELECT L.TicketNo ,L.Code,C.* FROM `ar` C  left join  `arlog` L ON C.TicketNo = L.TicketNo where C.provider='your condition' and L.status NOT IN('New','Completed','Completed(Ar_aging)','Completed(Rework)','Rework','Completed_Followup','Completed_Supervising' ) and L.assign='your condition' order by by C.id desc
```

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use CONCAT_WS()

There is a nice example of its usage in below link

[MySQL SELECT AS combine two columns into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860233/mysql-select-as-combine-two-columns-into-one)