# Consolidate columns into one column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view which produces data like this:

```
Event       Date        US_City     CA_City     ME_City     Br_City
Baseball    6/3/2016    LA          
Darts       5-Jun                   Ont     
Cricket     5-Jun                               Mexico City 
Football    6-Jun                                           Rio De Janero
```

What I want to end up with is something like this, where the city is in one column and not spread across multiple columns:

```
Event       Date        City    
Baseball    6/3/2016    LA          
Darts       5-Jun       Ont     
Cricket     5-Jun       Mexico City 
Football    6-Jun       Rio De Janero
```

I wasn't able to find a way to do this in SQL (more specifically, MySQL).  Are there aggregate functions or similar that I can use here?

Comment: show your view, it could be corrected there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT AS combine two columns into one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860233/mysql-select-as-combine-two-columns-into-one)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
Select Event, Date, coalesce(US_City,CA_City,ME_City,Br_City) city
from yourtable
```

Coalesce function returns the first non-NULL value in the list of cities, and assign it to `City`