# Sorting Two MySQL Table Columns as One

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different fields which will either or will contain a date `due_on_date` and `date_begin`. If one does not have a date in it, the other one will.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE this = 'that' 
 ORDER 
    BY due_on_date ASC
     , date_begin ASC
```

Is it possible to sort by these 2 columns but as one?

**For Example**

due_on_date has these three dates

```
01/01/20017
05/01/2017
08/01/2017
```

date_begin has these three dates

```
02/01/2017
04/01/2017
07/01/2017
```

The final sort order would look like

```
01/01/20017
02/01/2017
04/01/2017
05/01/2017
07/01/2017
08/01/2017
```

What I don't want to do is sort by one first then the other, I want the statement to sort as one column if that makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "sort by these 2 columns but sort it as one".  Where's your example????  Here's something to read.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL SELECT AS combine two columns into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860233/mysql-select-as-combine-two-columns-into-one)

Comment: @ObsidianAge No I dont want to combine columns, I want to sort them as one

Comment: `ORDER BY COALESCE(due_on_date,date_begin)` ?

Comment: That's the exact same thing. Combine the two columns as a new field with `CONCAT` (or `CONCAT_WS`), then sort by the combination.

Comment: If you coalesce or concat you can create a new column just for sorting, and leave the rest as-is.

Comment: Coalesce returns the first non-null value, it doesn't combine them. Concat (possibly after converting dates to strings) will do what you want, assuming you want it to sort as a long string.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry that question did have the answer and worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Not me, but you're welcome anyway

Comment: Hi. What does "fields which will either or will contain" mean? What does "doesn't contain a date" mean?PS Please read [ask] & google my comments on googling many variations of your question before considering asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean you want to order by the lowest non-null value,

```
ORDER BY LEAST(
   IFNULL(due_on_date, NOW()+INTERVAL 10 year),
   IFNULL(date_begin, NOW()+INTERVAL 10 year)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE this = 'that' 
ORDER BY concat(date_format(due_on_date,'%Y-%m-%d'),date_format(date_begin,'%Y-%m-%d')) asc
```